# Python: count files in specifically named subdirectories

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.walk

I'm trying to make a nagios check to count the number of files in any subdirectory name "failed" under a given directory and then check for a max_files threshhold. It's sort of like doing something like `` for i in `find . -type d -name failed`; do echo $; ls |wc -l $i; done `` in bash. (Trying to learn more Python instead of falling back to bash. Yes, that command probably doesn't work as written, just posted for illustrative reasons.)

I've cobbled together this method, which actually does what I want it to, but I can't seem to get rid of all the redundant output it generates. I've tried re-ordering the for loops, but to no avail. So I'm obviously missing something super simple.

```
import os, fnmatch

def count_files_in_subd():
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
       print "{} in {}".format(len(files), root)
       for dirname in fnmatch.filter(dirs, 'failed'):
           print "{} in {}".format(len(files), root)

count_files_in_subd()
```

This is all before I start doing the comparing the file count to threshholds, but I'm stuck on this part and can't seem to knock loose the thinking required to continue.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I'm looking for something along the lines of:

``/path/to/dir: 4 files``
``/path/to/anotherdir: 0 files``

etc.

Could be as simple as ``dirName 4`` too. I don't need anything elaborate.

(Pardon weird formatting and edits, I'm new here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir

def count_files_in_subd(path):
    files = listdir(path)

    if 'failed' in files:
        failed_files = listdir(path + 'failed/')
    else:
        print("There is no failed directory.")
        return

    print("There are {} files in the directory {}".format(len(failed_files), path))
```

`listdir(path)` returns a list of all files in the path. Getting the length of `listdir(path)` using `len()` will return the number of objects in the list.

Alternatively, this couple be simplified to:

```
print("{}:    {}".format(path + 'failed/', len(listdir(path)))
```

Comment: Thank you. That works to count the files in the path I pass to the function. But I need it to find any subdirectory name ``failed'' in the path I pass to the function (and count the files in each failed dir it finds). Sorry if I was unclear in OP. I'll see if I can use your (so much simpler than what I've been coming up with) code to figure it